# PhsyicalMemory condition always fails on bundle/bootstrapper installation for WiX 3.6

Tags: wix, wix3, wix3.6

The condition for PhysicalMemory always fails when using the bal extensions. I can try PhysicalMemory >= 3500 and PhysicalMemory < 3500 and PhysicalMemory >= 0. No matter what, the condition fails.

I want to verify the computer has 4GB of RAM before starting the bundle installation and give them a custom message.

If I add the condition to the Bundle tag, it works but always says "the specified program requires a newer version of windows". I do not know how to customize this message.

(As a side note: VersionNT > 6.0 condition works properly)

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
     xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
  <Bundle Version="1.0.0" UpgradeCode="XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-AFD8530214A6" Name="My Bundle Name" DisableModify="yes">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication ThemeFile="RtfTheme.xml" LocalizationFile="RtfTheme.wxl" SuppressOptionsUI="yes" LicenseFile="license.rtf" LogoFile="logo.png"/>
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <bal:Condition Message="My Custom Message">
      PhysicalMemory >= 3500
    </bal:Condition>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

PhysicalMemory isn't a built-in Burn variable. Burn duplicates many, but not all, of the built-in MSI properties. [Here's a complete list.](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/bundle_built_in_variables.htm)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This explains why PhysicalMemory does not work. Is there an alternate option? Can you customize the message that is displayed t othe user if you use the Condition field on the "Bundle"?

Comment: Bundle/@Condition is used only when the bootstrapper application couldn't load; its message can't be changed.